# How to validate a text value in two different places

Tags: java, text, dynamic, compare, cucumber

I am having a scenario where i am pulling the text from an API and displaying in a callout say Text A (Ex - Address of a dealer in three lines) and I am pulling the zipcode value from Text A and doing a link decoration in the bottom of the page with Text B.

So i need to compare the text in Text A & B and pass the scenario if both are same, can someone please help.

Using Java Selenium.

Thanks
Venkat

Comment: Just use `assert.assertequals(Teaxt A, Text B);`

Comment: Thanks kusal, i figured it out and using the same method. Thank you for the reply though.